# show only file name(without extension ie., jpg, .bmp..) of the image added in a cell through file dialog-excel vab

Tags: excel, vba

im new to excel-vba.
i want to display the file name of the picture (without extension ie., jpg, .bmp..etc) added from the 'file dialog' in a specific cell (ie.,$M$3 or 'photograph').
here the code i tested. but here it is showing as picture name (ie., picture1, picture20, picture15 etc...), i want to show as picture file name as '100' (say file name is 100.jpg).

My main motto is to allowing photo to insert into cell, only when its picture file name is matches with $D$9 cell value (say, cell value is 100) and prevent adding of photo when file not matches.

```
Option Explicit
' Add photo button
Sub addphoto()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
   Dim profile As String
   'Dim filename As String
   On Error GoTo 0
   Dim fd As FileDialog
   'Dim pictureName As String

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.EnableEvents = False

   Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
   With fd
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Picture Files", "*.bmp;*.jpg;*.gif;*.png"
    .ButtonName = "Select"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Choose Photo"
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
    .Show

    If (.SelectedItems.Count = 0) Then ' to overcome vba error while   closing/canceling without any photo selection
    '// dialog dismissed with no selection
    Exit Sub
 End If

'filename = Application.GetOpenFilename
'MsgBox Application.GetOpenFilename

 End With
 ActiveSheet.Range("$M$3").Select

 With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fd.SelectedItems(1))
  On Error Resume Next
    .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("photograph").Left + 1
    .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("photograph").Top + 1
    .Placement = 1
    .PrintObject = True
    profile = .Name
    'pictureName = ActiveSheet.Range("photograph").Select 'This is the   picture name
    'MsgBox ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pictureName).Name
    MsgBox profile
   On Error GoTo 0
 End With

 ActiveSheet.Pictures(profile).Select
 With Selection.ShapeRange
   On Error Resume Next
    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .Width = 81        ' resizing the photo 85
    .Height = 93       ' resizing the photo 97
   On Error GoTo 0
 End With

 Application.EnableEvents = True
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123", userinterfaceonly:=True

 End Sub
```

Comment: The usual way of getting rid of a file extension would be `Left(x, InstrRev(x, ".")-1)` (assuming `x` is a variable that contains the full file name).

Comment: How to display file name of the image added in a cell? I used        'profile = .Name'        for name display, but it is showing as picture1, picture2, picture12.... i want to show as picture file name as '100' (say file name is 100.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
profile = .Name
```

with these:

```
profile = fd.SelectedItems(1)                           'Gets Fullname of file inserted
profile = Dir(profile)                                  'Gets Filename only
profile = Left(profile, InStrRev(profile, ".") - 1)     'Removes file extension
```

Comment: Why? Why do you need the first line, its result is obliterated in the second line without being relevant. Why not, in the second line, use something different than "profile" - you know, something random, file filename, just so someone has  a clue later what is going on?

Comment: @BillWoodger both lines are needed, see the comments beside. it could go in one line but been this the problem area for the OP's I choose to do it in separated lines to better show how it's done. No my choice on the name of the variable, just using same variable that Op is using in order to reduce possibilities for confusion from Op's part.

Comment: @sureshkumar If this solves your problem, then next step for you is to accept the answer, that's an effective way of saying thanks beyond words and help us to keep the site updated.

Comment: Well, now that you've changed the code... You are supposed to say "thanks for spotting that", not "both lines are needed" :-) You may not feel you have a choice on the final variable-name, but that does not dictate using the same variable-name for everything, does it? I read the comments at the time, and, as usual, it doesn't matter what the comments say, what matters is what the code does. So now we know that either what you coded originally doesn't work or you don't need the first line. Never mind, OP's happy

Comment: How to check if specific cell is empty or has a picture?

Comment: from the above code i want to display the message box that does the cell M3 has picture or not?      ' ActiveSheet.Range("$M$3").Select '            that current sheet has many objects/pictures at different cell locations, i want to show the message for specific location (M3) only.